# Equivalent MATLAB code from the Mathematica code

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I have the following in Mathematica

```
n=5;
Xt = Table[t^i, {i, 0, n}]
```

The Mathematica outputs the following:

```
{1, t, t^2, t^3, t^4, t^5}
```

I want the equivalent MATLAB code. Please note the symbolic representation of the `t` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> syms t;
>> n = 5;
>> Xt = t.^(0:n) 

Xt =

[ 1, t, t^2, t^3, t^4, t^5]
```

Comment: Thanks, but why this code does not work?

`n=5;
t=sym('t');
Xt=zeros(n+1,1);
for i=0:n
    Xt(i+1)=t.^(i);
end`

Comment: Because `Xt` is a numerical / `double` array. You're trying to assign a symbolic variable to a numerical array and in this case, that syntax is not allowed in MATLAB.  I suggest you read up on how symbolic variables work: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/creating-symbolic-variables-and-expressions.html.  You should also read the error message you get carefully... it's pretty insightful.